# If statement don't works in sh file

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh, heredoc

Good day.

I want to automatize certain process with linux and bash. And I stuck in a IF statement.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(
 sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
 CONNECT admin/password@server;

 whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
 set echo off
 set heading off
 @processQuery.sql
 exit;
 EOF
)
echo $result
if [ "$result" != "no rows selected" ]
then echo "Please, clean up"
else echo "All Ok"
fi
```

And the output is:

```
no rows selected
Please, clean up
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Update: add

```
result2=${result:1}
```

and

```
if [ "$result2" != "no rows selected" ]
```

Thank you so much and specialy to @mercury0114 for the answer!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Doesn't that contain spaces at the end of strings?

Comment: What does `echo ${result@Q}` look like? (with `bash`, that should show if there are extra chars in `result`)

Comment: @noam my question is why I don't get the expected result.

Comment: @Yuji When I try `echo "."$result"."` I get `. no rows selected.` but when I put that in IF statement return the same wrong result.

Comment: @Cyrus I put that on a .sh file.

Comment: @user13828779 `echo ${result@Q}` returns me an error: `bad substitution`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `result` variable does not contain spaces or something else?
Because for me the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
result="no rows selected"
echo $result
if [ "$result" != "no rows selected" ]
then echo "Please, clean up"
else echo "All Ok"
fi
```

Prints

```
no rows selected
All Ok
```

I would double check what the SQL query returns.

Also, consider replacing `"$result"` by just plain `result`:

```
if [ result != "no rows selected" ]
```

Comment: I try with `echo "."$result"."` and I get: `. no rows selected.` I put `" no rows selected"` with the same result. using `result` instend of `$result` no change. Thanks.

Comment: @EnriqueLorenzoVillarMavila so why the space betwen `.` and `n`? Shouldn't it be `.no rows selected.`?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why appears that space, but no changes in IF statement with that. Maybe I need convert the output of SQLPLUS but I don't know how.

Comment: well to remove the first space do "${result:1}"